# localstorage in outlook desktop clinet

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Can we make use of localstorage in outlook desktop client?

During debugging of outlook web add-in the typeof(storage) always returns undefined. Does this happen because of localhost?

I know I could have used roming setting instead of localstorage but data exceeds 31kb.

Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:-->
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" 
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id></Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>addinName</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="addinNameOutlook" />
  <Description DefaultValue="addinNameOutlook"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/addinName64.png"/>

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.addinName.com" />
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MessageRead.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/addinName16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/addinName32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/addinName80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/login.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="addinName Outlook"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="addinName Outlook BETA"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="addinName Outlook BETA"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="addinName Outlook BETA"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Allows you to upload mail"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Please let me know if you need any information.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use "window.localStorage".  A bunch of add-ins (like Script Lab) do all the time.  Are you encountering an issue when you do?

Comment: Now I'm able to access it. There is no error as such, I'm using vs2017 to debug code. I'm setting localstorage in one page and trying to access it another HTML page. But when I try to access the saved storage, it returns null.

Comment: Are both pages on the same domain?  Localstorage (in any browser, irrespective of office add-ins) is per domain.

Comment: both are on the same domain.

Comment: Can you access the localstorage right after you set it from the same page?  Are both pages part of an addin? Or is 1 page in an add-in and the other page in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I can access it after I set it on the same page. Both the pages are part of the same add in

Comment: Could you share a manifest that includes simple repro? We have not been able to reproduce this issue, and want to gather more information.

Comment: I've updated my question with manifest file. Sorry for the delay

Comment: @Katari I think you are running into a bug in IE (we have the same issues)
IE has issues synchronizing the localstorage in different tabs https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/110656/

Same happens in Outlook

Comment: @DarkLegend Yes. I faced this issue in IE.

Comment: @Katari, I've ran into this issue as well when developing Script Lab.  See the "ensureFreshLocalStorage" function that we ended-up writing:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/d60fd3a1ce30a878dfc3c7b2c3bdb351d2bfd8d1/src/client/app/helpers/utilities.ts#L322